# Immediately invoked functions in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

Could someone show me how to immediately invoke a function in CoffeeScript. I'm trying to accomplish something similar to this JS object literal.

```
WEBAPP = {
    maxHeight : function(){
        /* Calc stuff n' stuff */
        WEBAPP.maxHeight = /* Calculated value */
    }(),
    someProperty : ''
    /* ... */        
}
```

Is it possible or what are the workarounds?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is `do`:

```
WEBAPP = 
  maxheight: do -> 1+1
  someProperty: ''
```

Which compiles to

```
var WEBAPP;

WEBAPP = {
  maxheight: (function() {
    return 1 + 1;
  })(),
  someProperty: ''
};
```

Comment: If that seems weird, `(-> 1+1)()` will do the same thing as `do -> 1+1`.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else coming across this question, you can also combine the `do` keyword with default function parameters to seed recursive "immediately-invoked functions" with an initial value. Example:

```
do recursivelyPrint = (a=0) ->
  console.log a
  setTimeout (-> recursivelyPrint a + 1), 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

why won't you try something like this?

```
square = (x) -> x * x

WEBAPP = {
   maxHeight: square(3),
   someProperty: ''
}
```

**UPDATE**

BTW: this is other workaround

```
WEBAPP = {
   maxHeight: (() -> 
       1 + 2
   )()
}
```